Inequalities on the distribution of the maximum of the normalized sum $\max_{k = 1,\dots,n} \frac{|S_k|}{\sqrt{k}}$
Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$,$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sigma^2$ and finite moments. Let $S_k = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} X_i$ and consider the normalized quantity
$$V_n = \max_{k = 1,\dots,n} \frac{|S_k|}{\sqrt{k}}$$
Darling and Erdos proved that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left\{V_n<(2\log{\log{n}})^{1/2}+\frac{\log{\log{\log{n}}}}{2(2\log{\log{n}})^{1/2}}+\frac{t}{(2\log{\log{n}})^{1/2}}\right\} = \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-t}\right)}
$$
moreover Darling and Siegert proved that:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(|S_n|\leq\alpha\sqrt{n},n_1\leq n\leq n_2\right) \approx \mathbb{P}(|X(t)|\leq\alpha,\frac{1}{2}\log{n_1}\leq t\leq\frac{1}{2}\log{n_2})
$$
where $X(t)$ is the Ulhenbeck process.  In our case $n_1 = 1$ , $n_2 = n$.
Question
I would like to know for the first one if there is a theorem regarding the rate of convergence of that probability to its limit. Furthermore, for the second one, since it's an approximation, I would like to know how tight is to the real value (is it bigger? Smaller? ..) In general, given $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ my aim is to bound probabilities like:
$$
\mathbb{P}(V_n < \alpha)
$$
where $n$ is a fixed positive integer.
Idea and clarifications
There are works that describes the rate of convergence of a random walk to Brownian motion.. but the problem is that they consider probabilities like $$
F_n(\alpha) = \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\max_{k = 1\,\dots,n}|S_k|}{\sqrt{n}} < \alpha \right)
$$
which converges to:
$$
F(\alpha) = \mathbb{P}\left(\max_{0\leq t\leq 1} |W(t)| \leq \alpha\right)
$$
as $n\to\infty$, and they bound $|F_n(\alpha)-F(\alpha)| \leq g(n,\alpha)\to 0$.
My goal is to find a similar result for $G_n(\alpha) = \mathbb{P}(V_n \leq \alpha)$.
For references see:
Darling, Siegert: The First Passage Problem for a Continuous Markov Process
Darling, Erdos: A limit theorem for the maximum of normalized sums of independent random variables
Fraser: The Rate of Convergence of a Random Walk to Brownian Motion
